# Characterization of open sets that are union of countably many closed sets in normal spaces

Tags: general-topology

> Let $Y$ be a topological space and consider the family of sets $\{y\in Y\mid f(y)>0\}$, where $f$ is a continuous real-valued function on $Y$.
>
> I want to show that, if $Y$ is a normal space, then the elements of such family are exactly the open subsets of $Y$ which are unions of countably many closed sets.

One impliation is trivial, since $f^{-1}(]0,\infty[)=\bigcup_n f^{-1}([\frac{1}{n},\infty[)$.

Conversely, I argued as follows: let $A$ an open subset of $Y$ which is countable union of closed sets $C_n$.
Wlog, we may assume $C_n\subseteq C_{n+1}$.
For any fixed index $n$, Urysohn's Lemma ensures the existence of a continuous function $f_n\colon Y\to [0,1]$ s.t. $f_n(Y\setminus A)=0,f_n(C_n)=1$.

**NOTE:** From now on, I'm not sure what I've done is correct.

I tried to show that $Y\setminus A =\bigcap_n f_n^{-1}(0)$, so that $A=\bigcup_n f_n^{-1}(]0,\infty[)$.

$(\subseteq)$ Clear. $(\supseteq)$ Suppose there is $x\in\bigcap_n f_n^{-1}(0)\setminus (Y\setminus A)\subseteq A$.
By definition, $f_n(x)=0$ for every $n$, but there exists $N$ s.t. $x\in C_N$, hence $f_N(x)=1$, contradiction.

If the above is correct, I proved $A=\bigcup_n f_n^{-1}(]0,\infty[)$. In order to conclude, I have to find continuous $f$ s.t. $A=f^{-1}(]0,\infty[)$.
My guess is that it is enough to choose $f=\bigcup_n f_n$ (because the sequence $C_n$ is increasing), but I was not able to go further.

My questions are:

(1) how can I prove (or disprove) $f=\bigcup_n f_n$ is continuous? (recall that $Y$ is normal)

(2) if the above is uncorrect, how should I proceed?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: $\cup_n f_n$ is not a function. Use a sum, see below.

Comment: @Henno Why is $f=\bigcup_n f_n$ defined $f(x)=f_n(x)$, when $x\in C_n$, not a function?

Comment: it might be a function if you consider them as partial functions, but why would it be continuous. No east theorems available.

Comment: east --> easy, I mean, and $f[O]=1$ and $f[X\setminus O]= 0$ does not really give a continuous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O$ be open with $O=\bigcup_n F_n$ a countable union of closed sets.

Then find Urysohn functions $f_n: X \to [0,1]$ with

$$f_n[F_n]=\{1\} \land f_n[X\setminus O]=\{0\}$$

Define $f=\sum 2^{-n}f_n: X \to [0,1]$, which is also continuous (absolutely convergent sum of continuous functions) and obeys $f(x)>0$ for $x \in O$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x \in O$, so $O=\{x: f(x)>0\}$.

Comment: I see, we need a Tiezte-type argument.

Comment: @LBJFS Tietze is more complex than this. This is applying Urysohn countably many times.

Comment: @LBJFS Extending a given function is harder than making one from scratch in this case, because these $f_n$ are already continuous and everywhere defined.